# File dialogue not getting close after file is downloaded

Tags: python, selenium

I have written a code in python selenium that will login to Jira and then open another URL that is to download a report file.

```
Step 1- driver.get(jira.com) # I will login on this page

Step 2- driver.get('Another Jira URL.com\file.csv?somthing something....')# This URL will give me a csv file to download if I will put this in browser directly.
```

after step 2 It will open file dialogue it's downloading file in .temp format in download folder and after `driver.quit()` not closing file dialogue. [image: screenshot]

Comment: I believe you are using firefox to download the file ?

Comment: using chrome to download file , chrome driver selenium

Comment: Strange,  can you attach a screenshot as well  of dialogue pop up ?

Comment: I have uploaded screenshot in question. In background it's downloading file

Comment: Please see below.

Comment: I have tried but still it's not working.

Comment: Can you share how did you implemented ?

Comment: Here is how I have implemented 'code'  ops = Options()
        ops.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
          "download.default_directory": self.downloadFolder,
          "download.prompt_for_download": False,
          "download.directory_upgrade": True,
          "safebrowsing.enabled": True
        })
        
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path =r'C:\Users\ashutosh-k-tiwari\Desktop\Other Doc\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe',options = ops)
        
        url='another jira URL'
        driver.minimize_window()
        driver.get('https://jira.com/login.jsp')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `prompt_for_download` is set to **false**, so that you would not see that **download prompt at all**. Create an `options` and pass them like below and then **create object of chromedriver**

**Sample code :**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\xxx\downloads\Test",
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path, options = options)
```